# System.Drawing in XNA

Tags: c#, namespaces, xna-4.0

I am currently working on a 2D pinball game utilizing XNA and VS2010, and have run into problems.

First of all, I have two paddles, each with a bounding box. As far as I can tell though, it is impossible to rotate a Rectangle unless using the draw method. This type of rotation does not work though, as the Rectangle dimensions have not actually moved, it is just being drawn to do so.

I then moved on to using lines, and while trying to implement System.Drawing in order to use the Pen tool I found the namespace did not exist.

Suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should post some code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Nick

Within a paddle class i have separate functions for rotating the left/right paddles.

Comment: @Nick
`public void RotL(float gametime){

rotAngle += (gametime * speed);
rotAngle = rotAngle % CIRCLE_IN_DEGREES;
rads = rotAngle * (Math.PI / 180);

if (rotAngle <= MAX_ROTATION)
{
rotAngle = MAX_ROTATION;
speed = 1.0F;
Endpoint.X = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Cos(MAX_RADS));
Endpoint.Y = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Sin(MAX_RADS));
}
else if (rotAngle >= INIT_ROT)
{
data manipulation that mirrors the previous if clause, replacing MAX_RADS with INIT_RADS
}
else 
{
speed += 0.45F;
Endpoint.X = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Cos(rads));
Endpoint.Y = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Sin(rads));
}`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're confusing the actual gameplay paddle/rectangle elements and their images drawn to the screen.

Worry about how your game plays, how the paddles, balls, etc, move and rotate, then draw the images to match accordingly.

Also, consider posting code if you're having issues.

Comment: My code so far
@Nick
`public void RotL(float gametime){
rotAngle += (gametime * speed);
rotAngle = rotAngle % CIRCLE_IN_DEGREES;
rads = rotAngle * (Math.PI / 180);

if (rotAngle <= MAX_ROT)
{
rotAngle = MAX_ROT;

speed = 1.0F;
Endpoint.X = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Cos(MAX_RADS));
Endpoint.Y = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Sin(MAX_RADS));
}
else if (rotAngle >= INIT_ROT)
{
data manipulation that mirrors the previous if clause, replacing MAX_RADS with INIT_RADS
}
else 
{
speed += 0.45F;
Endpoint.X = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Cos(rads));
Endpoint.Y = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Sin(rads));
}`

Comment: @user2344574 Edit your question above.  Start it with "EDIT:", then post your code with code formatting.

Comment: Dont use those Caps variables. Normally C# follows camelCase and PascalCase.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not really an answer but an edit.  I don't have enuf points to edit your question yet, but the word-wrapped code was driving me buggy.  indent by at least 4 spaces to have it auto recognized as code.  also, you seem to be missing a portion of it.

```
    public void RotL(float gametime)
    {
        rotAngle += (gametime * speed);
        rotAngle = rotAngle % CIRCLE_IN_DEGREES;
        rads = rotAngle * (Math.PI / 180);
        if (rotAngle <= MAX_ROT)
        {
            rotAngle = MAX_ROT;
            speed = 1.0F;
            Endpoint.X = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Cos(MAX_RADS));
            Endpoint.Y = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Sin(MAX_RADS));
        }
        else if (rotAngle >= INIT_ROT)
        {
            data manipulation that mirrors the previous if clause, replacing MAX_RADS with INIT_RADS
        }
        else
        {
            speed += 0.45F;
            Endpoint.X = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Cos(rads));
            Endpoint.Y = (float)(PADDLE_WID * Math.Sin(rads));
        }
```