# Drawing lines in C# with XNA

Tags: c#, xna

There is a similar question [System.Drawing in XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347382/system-drawing-in-xna), but this may be a clearer question and thus one easier to answer.

We're trying to draw lines on the screen in C#.  We are using the XNA library.  This code

```
    void DrawLine2 (Vector2 point1, Vector2 point2)
    {
        System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 1);
        Point p1 = new Point((int)point1.X, (int)point1.Y), p2 = new Point((int)point2.X, (int) point2.Y);
        Graphics.DrawLine (pen, p1, p2);
    }
```

gives the compile-time error that Graphics does not exist.

Perhaps I should be using something in XNA to draw the line rather than in System -- but if so I am not sure what.  XNA has a Spritebatch drawing function, but AFAIK you give it a sprite and a center (and a rotation), rather than 2 points.

Comment: A one pixel (or larger) sprite stretched from one point to another with a rotation makes a line, if you don't want to get into actually drawing line primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spritebatch can be used to draw a line, as Beanish commented you can simply make a one pixel sprite and extend it between two points.

This is a great library for drawing 2D primitives in XNA that uses the technique for drawing lines, as well as other objects like arcs. I use it extensively:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/primitives2d/

Comment: @JohnMcDonald It's a great library. Thanks for making it!

Answer (score 10):

Try this handy extensions method,

```
public static void DrawLine(this SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 begin, Vector2 end, Color color, int width = 1)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle((int)begin.X, (int)begin.Y, (int)(end - begin).Length()+width, width);
    Vector2 v = Vector2.Normalize(begin - end);
    float angle = (float)Math.Acos(Vector2.Dot(v, -Vector2.UnitX));
    if (begin.Y > end.Y) angle = MathHelper.TwoPi - angle;
    spriteBatch.Draw(1X1 PIXEL TEXTURE, r, null, color, angle, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```